# How can I remove a phrase from a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have the following sample string

```
url?name=MyName&number=4112111122223333&code=123&fromdate=2013-10-11&type=room&todate=2013-10-12
```

Basically I want to remove anything after the &number,&code, &fromdate, &todate.  Can anyone offer any advice on the best way to approach this ?  Should I be looking to use RegEx ?  The resulting string should look like

```
url?&name=MyName&number=&code=&fromdate=&type=room&todate=
```

Comment: Use a regular expression. Google it, learn what it is, google how to use it in C#, then use it. Easy as pie (in your case anyway). Ah, and remember about regex greediness.

Comment: Regex is overkill for this (IMO).  You could use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString and then rebuild the query string the way you want it.

Comment: I'd say use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method to get you the name value parts, and then recreate again setting the parts you don't want to empty strings.

Comment: var result = Regex.Replace(yourStringVariable, "(?<=(&code=|&number=|&fromdate=|&todate=))[^&]+", "");

Comment: @Tobsey Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: @Tim A proper regex will give him an one-liner which does what he wants. `NameValueCollection` and the code required to handle it may be another kind of overkill. Besides, how do you know what is used in `ParseQueryString` internally? And why do you think performance is any issue here?

Comment: @Dariusz I think what @Tim meant is that the complexity of a regex is overkill. `ParseQueryString` could possibly be less performant, but it would be easier to work with and easier to understand when you read it half a year later.

Comment: @Tommo1977 I've added it as an answer now that the question is open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace(yourStringVariable, "(?<=(&code=|&number=|&fromdate=|&todate=))[^&]+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=url\?|&)(number|code|fromdate|todate)=[^&]+", "$1=");
```

Result on input:

> url?name=MyName&number=&code=&fromdate=&type=room&todate=

Comment: Your output is different from the desired output.

Answer (score -3):

use the `Regex.Replace()` method